# How to Compute real world co-ordinates from pixel coordinates of stereo Pair Camera

Tags: computer-vision, transform, camera-calibration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHw1W.png)
Attached is my image of the stereo-camera setup.

The camera 01 and camera 04 are in stereo pair looking at the object P. The camera pairs are calibrated and their intrinsic parameters are used to calculated the triangulated position of point P, relative to primary camera 01. Let’s say this position with respect to camera-01, P (x,y,z) <sub>T</sub> . I want to transform this coordinate to real world coordinate system of X, Y, Z whose origin lies at O. We know the position of both cameras on this system.

For extrinsic parameters, 37 points are plotted in observation cuboid whose x, y, z points in real world are known. The pixel coordinate of these points observed from stereo pairs are also known. The triangulated (x,y,z)<sub>T</sub>  are also computed from these pixel coordinates.

But, I have difficulty in transforming this to real world coordinate system.
Can someone help me with mathematical routine and matlab code

Here is the link to files needed.
It contains, two csv files on x, y pixel points of 37 points inside observation area.
Also, the real world x,y,z from origin O for cross-reference
The checkerboard calibration results .mat file

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_u_dYDo_seHHG4bPcZnKLXyuMMKJM48k?usp=sharing

I tried finding the rigid transformation matrix using x,y,z tranigulated 37 points and real world x,y,z position. But somehow didn't get correct answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.